# slideToggle function moves all

Tags: jquery

I have a slideToggle function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".widget-content-box").slideUp(); // $(".widget-content-box").hide()
    $("[id^=goal]").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
})
```

I have goal ids and when you click on any one of them they all drop down, though  the content only shows on the one i have clicked, which is fine, but is there a way to have the slideToggle dropdown for just the one selected and not drop all of the divs with the goal id

EDIT

HTML for this project

```
  <div class="span4">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-header">
      <i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>
       <h3 id="goal1" class="clickme">Core</h3>
    </div><!--/widgetheader-->
     <div class="widget-content-box">
      <p>Hello</p>


     </div><!--/widget content-->
    </div><!--widget-->
  </div><!--span4-->

  <div class="span4">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-header">
      <i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>
       <h3 id="goal2" class="clickme">Marathon Runners</h3>
    </div><!--/widgetheader-->
     <div class="widget-content-box">
      <p>test</p>


     </div><!--/widget content-->
    </div><!--widget-->
  </div><!--span4-->

  <div class="span4">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-header">
      <i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>
       <h3 id="goal3" class="clickme">Biceps</h3>
    </div><!--/widgetheader-->
     <div class="widget-content-box">
      <p>content</p>


     </div><!--/widget content-->
     </div><!--widget-->
    </div><!--span4-->
    </div>
   </div>
```

Thank you

any help appreciated

Edit

My page is set out like so

```
DIV1      DIV2      DIV3
DIV4      DIV5      DIV6
```

so when you click div1 for example everything moves down, rather than just div1 and div4.

Comment: Can you show  some example HTML associated with this JS please ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  slideUp/slideDown sets the height of the item and that's how it does the animation.  The items below it will move down the page when you slideDown content above it.  That's how your HTML layout works.

Comment: yes the ones below move, i understand that, but I have 3 divs in a row and all of those move at the same time aswell

Comment: I put your code in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tPgkM/ and it seems to work... not all goal divs are toggled, only the clicked one... what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I have just made an edit, apologies if i am not being clear

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("[id^=goal]").click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created [**jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/hXmmH/) I hope it is what you are looking for.

I have changed your html so that each 'div class="span4"' has two 'div class="widget" (Div1-Div4, Div2-Div5 etc.) in it like this.

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header">
            <i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>
            <h3 id="goal1" class="clickme">Core</h3>
        </div><!--/widgetheader-->
        <div class="widget-content-box">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div><!--/widget content-->
    </div><!--widget-->
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header">
            <i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i>
            <h3 id="goal1" class="clickme">Core</h3>
        </div><!--/widgetheader-->
        <div class="widget-content-box">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div><!--/widget content-->
    </div><!--widget-->
</div><!--span4-->
```

And I have added the following css to class 'span4'

```
.span4{
    float:left;
    margin : 20px;
    width:70px;
}
```

Rest of your jquery code is same.
Have a look at the fiddle and  I hope this helps.